# Probability of Binomial Distributions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have $ X, Y \sim Bin(N,1/2) $ independent variables, and I'm asked to find $ \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X > Y) $.

Considering the identity $ \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n} $, we can have a symmetry argument, saying $ \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X > Y) = \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(Y > X) $, and calculating $ \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X > Y) = 0.5(1 - \def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X = Y) )$, we see our answer is $ 0.5 - \frac{1}{2^{2N+1}}{2N \choose N} $

However, I thought of the following: if $ X = k, Y = m$, then $ N \ge k > m \ge 0 $, so we want to calculate the following:
$ \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1}\def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X = k, Y = m) $. Since they're independent, we can get
$$ = \sum_{k = 1}^{N}(\def\P{\mathbb P}\P(X = k) \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1}\def\P{\mathbb P}\P(Y = m)) $$ and we get $$ \frac{1}{2^{2N}} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} {N \choose k} \sum_{m = 0}^{k-1} {N \choose m} $$
Is my line of reasoning correct? If so, how do I proceed from here?

What are different ways to solve this?

Comment: It is hard to tell precisely what your question is.  Are you just asking how we can go from your expression at the bottom of the question (with the two sums) to the expression you gave earlier in the question?

Comment: Yes, that is part of my question: how can I evaluate that double sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use two equalities, 
(1). $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n} - 1$ 
(2). $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$ or $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n - 1$

Let $S = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m}$. By switching the order double summation (Fubini's Theorem), we get $S = \sum_{m = 0}^n\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{n}{m}\binom{n}{k}$. We further rename the indices by switching the "symbol" of $m$ and $k$ (just treat them as dummy variables, no math is needed here), so that $S = \sum_{k = 0}^n\sum_{m=k+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m}$.

\begin{align*} 2S &= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m} + \sum_{k = 0}^n\sum_{m=k+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m} \\
& =  \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m} + \sum_{k = 1}^n\sum_{m=k+1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{m} + \sum_{m=0+1}^n\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{m} \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}\left[\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m} - \binom{n}{k}\right] + \sum_{m=1}^n \binom{n}{m} \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \left[2^n - \binom{n}{k}\right] + (2^n-1) &\text{By equality (1)} \\
& = 2^n (2^n-1) - \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 + (2^n-1) &\text{By equality (1)}\\ 
& = 2^{2n} - 2^n - \left[\binom{2n}{n} - 1\right]+2^n - 1  &\text{By equality (2)}\\ 
& = 2^{2n} - \binom{2n}{n} \\
\implies S & = 2^{2n-1}-\dfrac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}
\end{align*}

Hence, dividing both sides by $2^{2n}$ gives the desired result.